# parse XML from curl POST response

Tags: php, xml, post, curl, simplexml

I am posting an XML file to a server using curl. Everthing works perfectly but I am not sure how to handle the response best way. I would like to parse it with simpleXML. With this request:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $XPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

if(curl_errno($ch))
print curl_error($ch);
else
print_r($data);
curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting this as response-string (browser source view)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Expires: Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5FD40C8D8F5EDC85E57AF39E877BE564; Path=/upp/; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 829
Date: Sun, 22 Apr 2012 08:59:10 GMT

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<authorizationService version='1'>
<body merchantId='635634545' status='accepted'>
<transaction refno='1234987' trxStatus='response'>
  <request>
    <amount>2000</amount>
    <currency>USD</currency>
  </request>
  <response>
    <responseCode>01</responseCode>
    <responseMessage>Authorized</responseMessage>
  </response>
</transaction>
```

How do I correctly parse $data with simpleXML.I mean getting rid of the header part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the header, set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false`.

Comment: As simple as that! Thanks a lot.